# WPF Control Manipulation

Tags: wpf

I need to dynamically add the controls to a window. For example for a comboBox, I need to map with the Custom Framework which will map the Lookup to that comboBox...

So whenever the combobox is mapped with lookup, I need to Add a (+) Button to the right side of the comboBox.. This (+) button is used to open a respective lookup form to add an item to the comboBox.

For that I need to do the following..

1. In Mapper I need to create instance for Button Label with (+),
2. I need to create a Panel., ie., Container for holding both the Controls (ComboBox,Button)
3. For replacing Combobox with that created panel, I need to remove the Combobox from the Parent of Combobox and add panel to that control.

How can we do this in WPF? ie. dynamically replacing controls in Code behind.

Thanks in advance, Dinesh

Comment: Please use proper spelling (remove all the capitals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using MVVM pattern with separation of View and ViewModel. To solve your issue you can use DataTemplates along with a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). Basically you should prepare different Data templates and depends on internal state of applicaiton / a particular ViewModel switch Views (XAML layouts).

**1) Define all templates in resources:**

```
   <!-- namespace where GridView .xaml and ChartView .xaml are -->           
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Gui.Views"
   ...

   <DataTemplate x:Key="GridDataTemplate">
        <views:GridView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChartDataTemplate">
        <views:ChartView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

**2) Specify selector in Control's presenter:**

```
<Control....
    <ContentPresenter 
       ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource YourDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

**3) Define selector in View's code behind:**

```
 private sealed class YourDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
 {            
      public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(
                                      object item, 
                                      DependencyObject container)
        {
            DataTemplate dataTemplate = null;
            IViewModel viewModel = item as IViewModel;
            if (viewModel.ViewType == Grid)
            {
               dataTemplate = this.Resources["GridDataTemplate"];
            }

            // ...
            return dataTemplate;                
        }
 }
```

**EDIT: Dynamically build controls**

- You can use [VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild.aspx) to traverse controls tree,
  find children controls, check whether they are of specific type and then remove/update
- You can reffer parent control by `control.Parent` property
- You can remove any child control using `(parent as Panel).Children.Remove()`
- You can add control using `(parent as Panel).Children.Add()`

Comment: Its ok, I am doing like that only.. The thing is I want to Repalce the Existing Controls in a Grid Or any other Container..

Comment: @dinesh : so you can have separate views per control type GridView.xaml, ChartView.xaml and then depends on state of ViewModel (ReportView == grid or Chart) select appropriate view

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking ?.. The simple questioin is, How can we get the Parrent(Grid) of Control(ComboBox)..Using that ComboBox.. ie., We know only instance of ComboBox.. Wtih that How can we replace that Combobox with Pannel(Combobox + Button) in Combobox's Parrent Control ie(Grid) Only in C# code ie., Programatically... :)

Comment: @dinesh : see EDIT part of my answer

Comment: So, Parrent will always refer Parrent of that control, ie If ComboBox is added to Grid It will be Grid or if Pannel it will be pannel right.. Because I win forms its is like that only.. but here in wpf most of people are using VisualTreeHeler... So that I confused..  Yes Thanks.. Is there any link which explains in detail ? .. :)

Comment: @dinesh : I've described you an approach, and details of each specific method is on MSDN. If you need to clarify any specific case please raise an answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4228/discussion-between-dinesh-and-sll)

Comment: In your Edit Part.. (parent as Panel) you have mention as Parrent as Pannel.. but here I don't know the Type of Parrent.. Is there any interface or base class for that all Containers.. I have seen IAddChild is an Interface common for that but In that I don't find any Remove method..

Comment: @dinesh : most often container is of ItemsControl type which provides both RemoveLogicalChild() and RemoveVisualChild() methods, see MSDN

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ContentControl`s? They give you ability to dynamically host any control based on user actions. `ContentControl`s are like visual placeholders.

http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/

You can always use `Trigger`s to replace content os a content control dynamcially...

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
           <ContentControl.Style>
             <Style>
               <Setter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeTemplate}" />
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsManager}"
                               Value="True">
                       <Setter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ManagerTemplate}" />
                   </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
   </StackPanel>
```

So based on if the bound `Employee` object has `IsManager=true` a new template is dipslayed under the stack panel for the manager employee..

Comment: I need to do it in different way.. so I need right solution.. ie., I need to Replace the Control in Grid programatically..

Comment: I dont get it ... what is "programmatically"? In the above example, in a `Button.Click` handler you can switch between employee template and manager template if `Employee.IsManager` is set to true.

Comment: Any reason why? WPF discourages hosting `Views` \ `Controls` from code behind. My code above replaces employee view with manager view that too from the code behind, isnt it?